# Understanding the exponential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ a bounded operator on a Hilbert space. Define the exponential operator by:
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^{A}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{A^{n}}{n!} (A^{0}=I)
\end{eqnarray*}

I undesrtand this exponential operator like this: If $x\in H$ then:
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^{A}(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^{n}(x)}{n!} (A^{0}(x)=x)
\end{eqnarray*}
But if I think in for example $(e^{A})^{2}$. How can I see this function? I understand $(e^{A})^{2}$ by the composition of $e^{A}$ with itself.

Answer (score 2):

The crucial aspect of the set $B(H)$, formed by all bounded operators  on the Hilbert space $H$, relevant to the
present question, is that $B(H)$  is a *Banach
algebra*.  In particular  it is equipped with:

- a real (or complex) vector space structure,
- a multiplication operation (if $S$ and $T$ are operators, then the *product* $ST$ is understood to be the composition
  $S\circ T$), and
- a norm (for an operator $T$ we define $\|T\|=\sup\{\|Tx\|: x\in H,\ \|x\|\leq 1\}$).

If $A$ is any algebra, $a$ is any element of $A$,  and
$$
  p(X) = \lambda _0 + \lambda _1X + \lambda _2X^2 + \cdots + \lambda _nX^n
  $$
is a polynomial,  one may make sense of $p(a)$ by
simply replacing the variable $X$ with $a$, that is,
$$
  p(a) := \lambda _0 + \lambda _1a + \lambda _2a^2 + \cdots + \lambda _na^n.
  $$

If  moreover $A$ is a *normed* algebra, and if
$$
  p(X) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda _kX^k
  \tag 1
  $$
is a formal power series,  one may  make sense of $p(a)$ in a similar way, that is,
$$
  p(a) := \lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{k=0}^n\lambda _ka^k
  \tag 2
  $$
provided the limit exists.

In addition, if $A$ is complete with respect to its norm, then the above limit is guaranteed to exist whenever  the radius of convergence of
(1) is bigger than $\|a\|$, because then
$$
  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \|\lambda _ka^k\| \leq    \sum_{k=0}^\infty |\lambda _k|\|a\|^k < \infty ,
  $$
so the series in (2) is absolutely convergent, and hence convergent by completeness.

The correspondence $p\mapsto p(a)$ enjoys many sensible algebraic properties, such as
$$
  (pq)(a) = p(a)q(a),
  $$
as long as all series  involved converge.

Thus,  for example,  once we know that
$$
  \exp(X)^2 =   \exp(2X),
  $$
it immediately follows that
$$
  \exp(A)^2 =   \exp(2A),
  $$
for every bounded operator $A$.

---

The correspondence $p\mapsto p(a)$ has many interesting generalizations,  where special properties of $a$ allow one to extend
the kind of functions $p$ used.  "Analytic",  "continuous",  and "Borel" functional calculi are search terms you might
like to try for these generalizations.